Why is my ANN in C# not converging despite tuning hyperparameters?
I have an ANN implemented from scratch in c#. However, it would not converge, what could be the problem with it? I tried different activation functions, different dataset. The dataset is generated randomly, but an ANN in Python works with the same dataset, so it is possible to train a neural network to the data.

    private NeuralNetworkData ReLU(NeuralNetworkData x)
    {
        double[,] res = new double[x.Data.GetLength(0), x.Data.GetLength(1)];
        for (int i = 0; i < res.Length; i++)
        {
            res[i, 0] = MathF.Max(0, (float)x.Data[i,0]);
        }
        return new NeuralNetworkData( res);
    }
    private NeuralNetworkData Softmax(NeuralNetworkData x)
    {
        double[,] res = new double[x.Data.GetLength(0), x.Data.GetLength(1)];
        double max = x.ToVector().Max(x => x);
        double[] exps = x.ToVector().Select(x => Math.Exp(x - max)).ToArray();
        double sumExps = exps.Sum();

        for (int i = 0; i < res.Length; i++)
        {
            res[i, 0] = exps[i] / sumExps;
        }
        return new NeuralNetworkData(res);
    }
    private NeuralNetworkData ReLUDerivative(NeuralNetworkData x) 
    {
        double[,] res = new double[x.Data.GetLength(0), x.Data.GetLength(1)];
        for (int i = 0; i < res.Length; i++)
        {
            res[i, 0] = x.Data[i, 0] > 0 ? 1 : 0;
        }
        return new NeuralNetworkData(res);
    }
    private void FeedForward(int index, int epoch)
    {
        if (epoch is 0 && index is 0)
        {
            Weights1 = Weights1.Transpose();
            Weights2 = Weights2.Transpose();
        }
        Input = Scale(DataFile.Data[index].Values).ToMatrix();
        Z1 = (Weights1 * Input) + Bias1;
        Hidden = ReLU(Z1);
        Z2 = (Weights2 * Hidden) + Bias2;
        Output =  Softmax(Z2);

        //Console.WriteLine($"N1: {Output[0]}, N2: {Output[1]}, N3: {Output[2]}");
    }
    private double Error(int index)
    {
        double localError = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Output.Data.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            localError -= (DataFile.Data[index].Label[i] * Math.Log(Output.Data[i, 0] + 1e-9));
        }

        return localError;
    }
    private NeuralNetworkData ElementWiseMultiply(NeuralNetworkData first, NeuralNetworkData second)
    {
        if (first.Data.GetLength(0) == second.Data.GetLength(0))
        {
            double[] res = new double[first.Data.GetLength(0)];
            for (int i = 0; i < res.Length; i++)
            {
                res[i] = first.Data[i, 0] * second.Data[i, 0];
            }
            return res.ToMatrix();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Two vectors are not the same length!");
        }
    }
    private void Backpropagate(int index)
    {
        Delta2 = Output - DataFile.Data[index].Label.ToMatrix();
        Output_Gradient = Delta2 * Hidden.Transpose();
        Bias2_Gradient = Delta2;

        Delta1 = ElementWiseMultiply(Weights2.Transpose() * Delta2 , ReLUDerivative(Z1));
        
        Hidden_Gradient = Delta1 * Input.Transpose();
        Bias1_Gradient = Delta1;

        Weights2 = Weights2 - (LearningRate * Output_Gradient);
        Bias2 = Bias2 - (LearningRate * Bias2_Gradient);

        Weights1 = Weights1 - (LearningRate * Hidden_Gradient);
        Bias1 = Bias1 - (LearningRate * Bias1_Gradient);
    }
    private double[] Scale(double[] data)
    {
        double[] res = new double[data.Length];
        double sum = data.Sum();
        for (int i = 0; i < res.Length; i++)
        {
            res[i] = data[i] / sum;
        }
        return res;
    }
}
public static class DoubleExtensions
{
    public static bool Any(this double[,] matrix, Func<double, bool> func)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                if (!func.Invoke(matrix[i, j]))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public static bool All(this double[,] matrix, Func<double, bool> func)
    {
        List<bool> isTrue = new List<bool>();
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                if (func.Invoke(matrix[i, j]))
                {
                    isTrue.Add(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    isTrue.Add(false);
                }
            }
        }
        return isTrue.All(x => x is true);
    }
    public static NeuralNetworkData ToMatrix(this double[] vector)
    {
        if (vector.Any(x => x != 0))
        {
            double[,] res = new double[vector.Length,1];
            for (int i = 0; i < res.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                res[i, 0] = vector[i];
            }
            return new NeuralNetworkData(res);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("No input.");
        }
    }
    public static NeuralNetworkData Transpose(this NeuralNetworkData matrix)
    {
        if (matrix != null)
        {
            double[,] res = new double[matrix.Data.GetLength(1), matrix.Data.GetLength(0)];
            for (int i = 0; i < matrix.Data.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < matrix.Data.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    res[j, i] = matrix.Data[i, j];
                }
            }
            return new NeuralNetworkData(res);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("No input provided!");
        }
    }
    public static double[] ToVector(this NeuralNetworkData matrix)
    {
        if (matrix.Data.GetLength(1) == 1)
        {
            double[] res = new double[matrix.Data.GetLength(0)];
            for (int i = 0; i < res.Length; i++)
            {
                res[i] = matrix.Data[i, 0];
            }

            return (res);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Matrix too big!");
        }
    }
    public static double[] Multiply(this double[] first, double second)
    {
        double[] res = new double[first.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < res.Length; i++)
        {
            res[i] = first[i] * second;
        }
        return res;
    }
}


Here is the NeuralNetworkData:
public class NeuralNetworkData
{

    private void FillMatrix()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Data.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Data.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                Data[i, j] = rnd.NextDouble() * 0.01;
            }
        }
    }
    public static NeuralNetworkData operator *(NeuralNetworkData first, NeuralNetworkData second)
    {
        if (first.Data.GetLength(1) != second.Data.GetLength(0))
            throw new Exception("Matrices cannot be multiplied!");

        double[,] res = new double[first.Data.GetLength(0), second.Data.GetLength(1)];

        for (int i = 0; i < res.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < res.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                double sum = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < first.Data.GetLength(1); k++)
                {
                    sum += first.Data[i, k] * second.Data[k, j];
                }
                res[i, j] = sum;
            }
        }

        return new NeuralNetworkData(res);
    }
    public static NeuralNetworkData operator *(double first, NeuralNetworkData second)
    {
        double[,] res = new double[second.Data.GetLength(0), second.Data.GetLength(1)];
        for (int i = 0; i < second.Data.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < second.Data.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                res[i, j] = second.Data[i, j] * first;
            }
        }
        return new NeuralNetworkData(res);
    }
    public static NeuralNetworkData operator +(NeuralNetworkData first, NeuralNetworkData second)
    {
        if (first.Data.GetLength(1) == second.Data.GetLength(1) &&
            first.Data.GetLength(0) == second.Data.GetLength(0))
        {
            double[,] res = new double[first.Data.GetLength(0), second.Data.GetLength(1)];
            for (int i = 0; i < res.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < res.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    res[i, j] = first.Data[i, j] + second.Data[i, j];
                }
            }
            return new NeuralNetworkData(res);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Not the same length.");
        }
    }
    public static NeuralNetworkData operator -(NeuralNetworkData first, NeuralNetworkData second)
    {
        if (first.Data.GetLength(1) == second.Data.GetLength(1) &&
            first.Data.GetLength(0) == second.Data.GetLength(0))
        {
            double[,] res = new double[first.Data.GetLength(0), second.Data.GetLength(1)];
            for (int i = 0; i < res.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < res.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    res[i, j] = first.Data[i, j] - second.Data[i, j];
                }
            }
            return new NeuralNetworkData(res);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Not the same length.");
        }
    }
}

Thanks for all the advice in advance.
I tried different learningRates, different number of neurons in the hidden layer. Unfortunately nothing has worked.
